# Can I get document.cookie without using javascript? Alternate in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I was doing something but I can't use JavaScript in it.

I want to get the cookies but without using javascript.

But I want to get the same output as of `document.cookie`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']` in PHP.

[`$_COOKIE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php) is an array containing all cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the same input as in document.cookie, but you can access directly them from $_COOKIE just like macaco said

if you need to set cookie you can do this by using the setcookie() method from php

http://www.php.net/setcookie

cheers